# Adding Smileys to UITextView or UITextField

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

Can any body guide me to add smileys to UItextField or UITextView?

As v get in iChat view which is also editable u can add/remove it as v have for iChat in Desktop.

Eg: Hello :) (this is smiley)

Thanks
Veena

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
NSRange range = {NSNotFound, 0};
NSString *s = @"This is a smiley :)";

range.location = 0;
range.length = [s length];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)"
                                    withString:@"\ue415"
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                    range:range];
```