# Showing custom emoticon in UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, emoticons

Can I show custom emoticon inside UItextFiled as iPhone's keyboard emoticons are getting displayed. I checked the document but didn't found any method.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389379/adding-smileys-to-uitextview-or-uitextfield][1]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616172/show-smiley-icons-into-an-uitextfield][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389379/adding-smileys-to-uitextview-or-uitextfield
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616172/show-smiley-icons-into-an-uitextfield

Answer (score 1):

You can Use The Following Code from [the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389379/adding-smileys-to-uitextview-or-uitextfield)

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {   

NSRange range = {NSNotFound, 0};
NSString *s = @"This is a smiley :)";

range.location = 0;
range.length = [s length];
s = [s stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":)"
                                    withString:@"\ue415"
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                    range:range];

  }
```